# Web Audio API: How to load another audio file?

Tags: html, audio

I want to write a basic script for HTML5 Web Audio API, can play some audio files. But I don't know how to unload a playing audio and load another one.  In my script two audio files are  playing in the same time,but not what I wanted.

Here is my code:

```js
var context, 
    soundSource, 
    soundBuffer;

// Step 1 - Initialise the Audio Context
context = new webkitAudioContext();

// Step 2: Load our Sound using XHR
function playSound(url) {
    // Note: this loads asynchronously
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    // Our asynchronous callback
    request.onload = function() {
        var audioData = request.response;
        audioGraph(audioData);
    };

    request.send();
}

// This is the code we are interested in
function audioGraph(audioData) {
    // create a sound source
    soundSource = context.createBufferSource();

    // The Audio Context handles creating source buffers from raw binary
    soundBuffer = context.createBuffer(audioData, true/* make mono */);

    // Add the buffered data to our object
    soundSource.buffer = soundBuffer;

    // Plug the cable from one thing to the other
    soundSource.connect(context.destination);

    // Finally
    soundSource.noteOn(context.currentTime);
}

// Stop all of sounds
function stopSounds(){
    // How can do this?
}


// Events for audio buttons
document.querySelector('.pre').addEventListener('click', 
    function () {
        stopSounds();
        playSound('http://thelab.thingsinjars.com/web-audio-tutorial/hello.mp3');
    }
);
document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click',
    function() {
        stopSounds();
        playSound('http://thelab.thingsinjars.com/web-audio-tutorial/nokia.mp3');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be pre-loading sounds into buffers once, at launch, and simply resetting the `AudioBufferSourceNode` whenever you want to play it back.

To play multiple sounds in sequence, you need to schedule them using `noteOn(time)`, one after the other, based on buffer respective lengths.

To stop sounds, use `noteOff`.

Sounds like you are missing some fundamental web audio concepts. This (and more) is described in detail and shown with samples in this [HTML5Rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro) and the [FAQ](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/01/Web-Audio-FAQ).

Comment: thanks,but I'm a beginner, I don't know how to reset AudioBuferSouceNode. I'll read the tutorial first.